# angular mat-table trying to implement mat-sort

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, angular-material-table

I'm trying to implement mat-sort on a mat-table but I'm getting some issues when trying to initialize the mat sort functionality. 
The sort properties are undefined:

[image]

Mat table:

```
<mat-table matSort #sort1="matSort" matSortActive="id" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear
                                               #table
                                               [dataSource]="dataSource">
                                        <ng-container matColumnDef="statusName">
                                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="customer.statusName">Status Name</mat-header-cell>
                                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">
                                                {{customer.statusName}}
                                            </mat-cell>
                                        </ng-container>
                                    </mat-table>
```

Component code:

```
@ViewChild('sort1', { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
ngOnInit(): void {

    const sortSubscription = this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));
    this.subscriptions.push(sortSubscription);

    this.dataSource = new InvoiceStatusDataSource(this.invoiceStatusService);

    this.loadItems(true);
}
```

in loadItems I have this:

```
 loadItems(firstLoad: boolean = false) {
        const queryParams = new QueryParamsModel(
            {},
            this.sort.direction,
            this.sort.active,
            this.paginator.pageIndex,
            this.paginator.pageSize
        );
        this.dataSource.loadItems(queryParams);
        this.selection.clear();
    }
```

As you can see in the screenshot at the top the sort property is undefined. 
Do I need to write some extra code to initialize that property?

Answer (score 1):

Is your `MatTable` in any `ngIf` capsulated? If true you have to set your sort in the `ngAfterViewInit` because your table isn't rendered and your 'MatSort' does not exist or you can add a setter which sets your `MatSort` when it exists.

````
@ViewChild('sort1', { static: false})set matSort(value: MatSort){
  if(this.dataSource && value) {
    this.dataSource.sort = value;
  }
}
```
````